# Cannot access JSON object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object

```
alert(typeof object)
//Output
Object
```

which returns the following string after

```
alert(JSON.stringify(object));

//Output object

[{
"locationId":"8",
"locationTypeId":"0",
"locationTitle":"Alberta Prices",
"locationAddress":"Alberta, Canada",
"locationStatus":"0",
"locationLatitude":"53.9332706",
"locationLongitude":"116.5765035",
"googleLocationId":"ChIJtRkkqIKyCVMRno6bQJpHqbA",
"lastModified":"2017-06-04 03:59:02",
"locationType":"SPORT",
"userId":"4"
}]
```

When I am trying to access any property of the object, I get 'Undefined';

```
alert(object.locationId);

//Output
Undefined
```

Comment: Try `object[0].locationId`

Comment: Thanks dude, can you explain why it does work like this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @SakiburRahman Pls check my answer. Object is an array not just one object.

Comment: Thanks @User3250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing like this `object[0].locationId`.
You object is an array not just a single object. Hope it clears it.

Answer (score 0):

You get `undefined` because you are trying to access `locationId` on an `Array` which clearly does not exist.

If you want to access a given item's `locationId` you have to access the array by index and then its property.

```
console.log(object[0].locationId); //8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the locationId value with following statement.

```
x = JSON.stringify(object)
x[0].locationId
 8
```

I had tried on chrome console it was working for me. Pop up (alert) box contains 8 value.